# Why is contextInitialized() called multiple times?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, stripes

I'm running a Stripes web app on Jboss 4.2.3.GA and am trying to call a method when I start JBoss.  I created a ServletContextListener like so:

```
public class TimerContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Inject
    private TimerManager timerManager;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent) {
        ((Injector) servletcontextevent.getServletContext().getAttribute(GuiceServletContextListener.KEY)).injectMembers(this);
        timerManager.stopAllTimers();
        timerManager.startTimer();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent) {

    }
}
```

and I added an entry in web.xml like so:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.lawless.web.servletContextListeners.TimerContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

but contextInitialized() is getting called 3 times when I start my server.  Any idea what the issue could be?  Thanks.

Comment: Put a basic `System.out.println` at the top of your `contextInitialized` to be sure you are seeing what you think you are seeing. By the way I have seen this kind of problem: A known bug when hooking up Tomcat to NetBeans for use in development results in [Tomcat double-launching the web app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16702011/642706).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  It was being called 3 times because I had 3 virtual hosts defined in my jboss-web.xml.  Not sure why it causes that behavior though.  If anyone can explain the reason I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

There will be only one `ServletContext` for each web application. `ServletContext` will be created while deploying the application (3 Virtual Hosts means deploying to 3 different hosts with 3 different IP addresses). Once the `ServletContext` is created, it will be used by all the servlets and JSP files in the same application. `ServletContext` is also called as the application scope variables in the web application scenario.

Source - http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/